# Access the VBA of a spreadsheet from within another sheet's VBA (or C# console app)?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a batch of spreadsheets with lots of VBA code and I wanted to write something which could check for function dependencies. I am changing code and need to find out which files depend on functions I am modifying.

Is there a way to access the VBA modules/functions of spreadsheet X either from a C# console application, or from VBA in spreadsheet Y (just a different spreadsheet to X)?

I want to access the VBA as text/anything parsable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) has examples of reading and writing code.

The Reference you need to add is this one:
[image]

The two sections you will be most interested in are:

> Listing All Procedures In A Module
>   Reading A Procedure Declaration